# ASP.NET MVC Partial View with Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partialviews

I have a scenario I want to use a partial view but I'm having issues with it passing data to the controller.  Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to do.

Objects:

- Customer
- Order

A Customer has an `IList<Order>` on it.  I want the partial view to allow the user to edit the information.  I can get the data to display but when the form posts the list under the Customer object is null.

I have also attempted to use a seperate form in my partial view.  When I do this if I create paramenters on the controller like so I get the data:

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrders(IList<Guid> id, IList<int> quantity, IList<Guid> productId)
```

But when I do this

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrders(IList<Order> orders)
```

The list is null.

If anyone has a better suggestion of how to achieve this let me know.

Comment: Can you post the HTML, I think it would help in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you referencing the fields in your view?  I'm thinking that it should be something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="orders.Index" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="oders[0].ID" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="orders[0].productId" value="4" />
<input type="text" name="orders[0].quantity" value="6" />

<input type="hidden" name="orders.Index" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="orders[1].ID" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="orders[1].productId" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="orders[1].quantity" value="15" />
```

See Phil Haack's blog entry on [binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for more info.

Comment: The fields are generated by a foreach so they end up with the same id and name currently.

Comment: Your suggestion lead me to finding a solution.  I had to add the .index line I forgot it.  Not sure whey we don't have a helper for that yet.

Comment: @cjibo: you may want to consider this post for your creation of the index... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013578/create-views-for-object-properties-in-model-in-mvc-3-application  Namely, look at the link from Steve Sanderson's Blog that gives you a codebase to generate the names with Guids, which works quite well.