# How to model many-to-many relationships?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, domain-model

I have a problem with a model in a asp.net mvc3 application.
First of all, i have a table with items, each item has e.g.: id,name and description
where i also have a user with: id, name

It looks somewhat like:

```
class item {int id, string name, string description}
class user {int id, string name}
```

Now i also have a table which maps these two things to each other, with foreign keys.
so each user can have * items and each item also can have * users.

Now i need to create controller and view for the item. this works fine, the problem is, that i just create a item, but i want to create a item and the mapping to a user in one step.

how to solve this problem in mvc? (e.g. i just can add one model in a view and this is the item in the create process)

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc 3 code-first, or database first approach?

Comment: do you have already database? or are you using code-first approach?

Comment: look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/q/289082/1437962

Comment: Then you first get models from Database schema, and follow my posted links on many-to-many relationship.it needs to work, let me know what u get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you need to add drop-down of users while creating an item. This will help to link each item to a user.

However, your particulate issue seems to be in **building many-to-many relationship in the model**. How to do this? Well, this is already nicely explained here - [ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, One-to-Many and Many-to-Many INSERTS](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/109/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-INSERTS)

In addition, I would strongly **suggest** to go through - [NerdDinner Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx). It will give you good start-up and solid background for development in asp.net mvc framework.
You may also refer to [Tutorial samples](http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples) in official website to learn and practice development in mvc.

Here is a link to complete code of the tutorial - [NerdDinner 2.0 Complete ASP.NET MVC Sample App](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/releases/view/45647)